# Publish Kafka outputs in Grafana

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi, filebeat

Using Filebeat, I publish raw data in Kafka. I'm using NiFi to consume this data (using ConsumeKafka_2_6). The output is a list queue with 1 row (I need to do this because the information didn't maintain the order if I send one row for each line) that looks like this:

```
{
  "@timestamp": "2022-06-21T18:18:29.651Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "8.0.0"
  },
  "log": {
    "offset": 3780214,
    "file": {
      "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Filebeat\\inputs-test\\2022-05-23T13.07.27.0 - Copy (2).log"
    }
  },
  "message": "@ 2022-05-23 12:25:39.879 [    30] [lap=126.18  uS]       Out of range",
  "input": {
    "type": "filestream"
  },
  "agent": {
    "version": "8.0.0",
    "ephemeral_id": "0c4c1a87-11f1-4f75-8512-fa489cf455e0",
    "id": "552ab611-0ffb-44f4-83bf-77334c35950d",
    "name": "VM001",
    "type": "filebeat"
  },
  "ecs": {
    "version": "8.0.0"
  },
  "host": {
    "name": "VM001"
  }
}{
  "@timestamp": "2022-06-21T18:18:29.651Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "8.0.0"
  },
  "message": "@ 2022-05-23 12:25:39.879 [    30] [lap=106.46  uS]       Zone finished unexpectdly. \n+Exception message: Zone is out of range\n+################################################\n+#   BEGIN OF STACK TRACE                       #\n+################################################\n+   Error \n+################################################\n+#   END OF STACK TRACE                         #\n+################################################",
  "input": {
    "type": "filestream"
  },
  "host": {
    "name": "VM001"
  },
  "agent": {
    "name": "VM001",
    "type": "filebeat",
    "version": "8.0.0",
    "ephemeral_id": "0c4c1a87-11f1-4f75-8512-fa489cf455e0",
    "id": "552ab611-0ffb-44f4-83bf-77334c35950d"
  },
  "ecs": {
    "version": "8.0.0"
  },
  "log": {
    "offset": 3780940,
    "file": {
      "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Filebeat\\inputs-test\\2022-05-23T13.07.27.0 - Copy (2).log"
    },
    "flags": [
      "multiline"
    ]
  }
}{
```

Now, I need to extract all the messages (in order) and apply a filter: only maintain the messages that say *out of range*.

I tried to use **EvaluateJsonPath** like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quejP.png)

but the output is the same list as the input. And then I tried to use **SplitJson** like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkwFN.png) but it doesn't work properly (it creates some GB of information inside the SplitJson processor)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you want to fix your data... Each object should be individual Kafka records... In other words, you shouldn't have characters`}{` together. To control order, just use one Kafka partition (not that that really matters because you can group by host/filename and order by offset)

Comment: I tried to use one Kafka partition, but the data was disordered. Do you know how to set the same partition?

Comment: I've not recently used filebeat with Kafka, so I'm not sure what you mean "disordered". If you are writing data from multiple `host.name`'s, then yes, data within the topic will be mixed, but log `offset`'s and `@timestamp` will always be increasing for the same host and same `file.path`

Comment: If you want to really extract/filter data, though, using ELK tools, I'd recommend starting with Logstash rather than NiFi

Comment: Disordered means that, when I send from one file something like: 1, 2, 3, 4, the output of the Kafka is 1, 4, 3, 2. I read that using Kafka is better because it works as a buffer, don't you think so?

Comment: How are you viewing the data from Kafka? Does it include the record offset? A Kafka record batch can be re-ordered, but that would be a Filebeat configuration... but I think you misunderstood. Logstash can write to Kafka; it is replacing Nifi here since that is what you're having problems with. It can also replace Filebeat... It's also unclear what Grafana is reading from, if not Elasticsearch. You cannot "output Kafka to Grafana"

Comment: @Newton have you considered leveraging [fluent-bit](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/). If you want you can also ship logs to ELK too. Compartively very light weight compared to logstash+fluentd.

You can have a custom output plugin(in go-lang) to expose  log derived metrics/logs as prometheus metrics(using push gateway) and allow prometheus  to scrape them(grafana dashboard on them).

Comment: @OneCricketeer the architecture is filebeat -> kafka -> data processing (nifi) -> elasticsearch -> grafana. Do you say that I can send one row at a time (knowing that the output from Kafka will be disordered) and order that information based on timestamp and offset?

Comment: The message has characters }{ when you have a new message in the same partition. I tried using just one partition and also using 6 differente partitions, and the characters }{ appears always

Comment: Something isn't properly producing JSON data. Each log line should be a separate Kafka record. For example, [JSONlines](https://jsonlines.org/examples/) format. Otherwise, no JSON parser is going to work.

Answer (score 0):

> In Grafana

Grafana needs a datasource, such as Elasticsearch. You cannot write to it directly from Kafka.

If you used Filebeat with Logstash rather than Kafka, that would allow you to parse and filter the data there, then write to Elasticsearch as an output, never needing to use Kafka or NiFi.

> read that using Kafka is better because it works as a buffer

So can Logstash with [Persistent Queues](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/persistent-queues.html).

---

---

In any case....

> The output is a list queue with 1 row

Given input

```
@ 2022-05-23 12:25:39.879 [    30] [lap=126.18  uS]       Out of range
@ 2022-05-23 12:25:39.879 [    30] [lap=106.46  uS]       Zone finished unexpectdly.
+Exception message: Zone is out of range
+################################################
+#   BEGIN OF STACK TRACE                       #
+################################################
+   Error
+################################################
+#   END OF STACK TRACE                         #
+################################################
```

You can pre-parse some fields from that log

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: filestream
  enabled: true
  id: my-filestream-id
  paths:
    - /tmp/filebeat/*.log
  parsers:
    - multiline:
        type: pattern
        pattern: ^@
        negate: true
        match: after

processors:
  - drop_fields:
      fields: ["agent", "log", "input", "host", "ecs" ]
  - dissect:
      tokenizer: "@ %{log_time} [%{number}] [lap=%{lap_time}] %{log_message}"
      field: "message"
      target_prefix: ""
  - timestamp:
      field: log_time
      layouts:
        - '2006-01-02 15:04:05.999'
  - drop_fields:
      fields: [log_time]

#output.console:
#  pretty: true

output.kafka:
  hosts: ["localhost:9092"]
  version: 2.6.0
  topic: foobar
```

To guarantee log order, use one partition.

```
kafka-topics --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic foobar --partitions=1 --replication-factor=1
```

Example event

```
{
    "@timestamp": "2022-05-23T12:25:39.879Z",
    "@metadata": {
        "beat": "filebeat",
        "type": "_doc",
        "version": "8.2.3"
    },
    "message": "@ 2022-05-23 12:25:39.879 [    30] [lap=126.18  uS]       Out of range",
    "number": "    30",
    "lap_time": "126.18  uS",
    "log_message": "      Out of range"
}
```

And this is the first event (**of 2**) being consumed. Kafka nor Nifi should re-order them, so its unclear what you've meant by "disordered".

> extract all the messages (in order) and apply a filter: only maintain the messages that say out of range

The records are already JSON, so there is nothing that needs evaluated, only parsed, which you can do programmatically with `ScriptedFilterRecord`

[image]

Then in the outgoing success queue, we have the one filtered event for the string `Out of range`, but **not** `out of range` from `"Zone is out of range"` in the second event.

[image]