# Apache Nifi ConsumeKafka is not reading Topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I'm going to fetch messages from a certain topic in Apache Kafka and record them in an Oracle database. The problem is the ConsumeKafka_1_0 1.17.0 processor is not reading the messages that are in the Kafka topic.

I tried to use versions of ConsumeKafka_1_0, ConsumeKafka_2_0 and ConsumeKafka_2_6;

I set Offset Reset to Latest or Earliest;

I modified the Group ID on each request;

I set Honor Transactions to True or False;

My Kafka server is on the same network and doesn't use any credentials of Kerberos or TSL tickets. Configured on default port 9092 and using Zookeper on another server.

I accessed the Broker server, where the topics are and successfully executed the command to list the Topics and Messages.

Other processes here at the company where I work use Kafka without any problems.

Has anyone had this issue and managed to resolve it?

[image: 1]

Comment: Latest offset reset starts at the end of the topic, so are you producing data?

Comment: Thank you very much for replying OneCricketeer.
Well the topic is constantly fed with data. I already set Offset Reset to Latest or Earliest, and it didn't work.

Comment: Well, your settings look fine, so maybe look at the logs? I do have an end to end answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72807266/2308683

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. I don't know much about NiFi, I'm still a newbie. I had a good read on your topic about Logs, but I confess that I didn't understand how to do it.

Comment: If your goal is to write data to Oracle, why not use Kafka Connect JDBC sink instead?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I need to run an ETL process on the messages that are in the Kafka topic, and then export to the Oracle database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> tried to use versions of ConsumeKafka_1_0, ConsumeKafka_2_0 and ConsumeKafka_2_6

Depends what Kafka version you are using. If you are using Kafka broker later than 2.6, then use that. If you are newer than 2.0 broker, but less than 2.6, use 2.0... and so on.

> set Offset Reset to Latest or Earliest

Depends if you care about existing data. If so, use earliest.

> modified the Group ID on each request

That's a good debugging step, but not necessary all the time. You can use `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` command to further debug if the group was actually created in the Kafka cluster.

> Honor Transactions to True or False

Depends if your producer uses transactions. Not sure what NiFi will do if you have this set to true, and your producer doesn't use them... Probably safe to leave set to True, though.

---

#### Example w/ latest Kafka

For PLAINTEXT Kafka protocol

- security.protocol=PLAINTEXT
- sasl.mechanism=PLAIN (cannot be disabled, so username + password are needed)
- Username: some non-empty string
- Password: some non-empty string

For simple Kafka consumer debugging

- Record Reader: [`GrokReader`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.grok.GrokReader/additionalDetails.html)

  - Configure with Grok Expressions: `%{GREEDYDATA:message}`

For internal Nifi FlowFile output (could use any format, but JSON is good to validate your steps have worked)

- Record Writer: `JSONRecordSetWriter`

Add new processors for `parse.failure` (or terminate it under the Relationships tab) and setup `success` relationship with click-drag from Consume Processor. You can disable next processor to simply queue up FlowFiles within NiFi.

Then, start the Consume processor, and inspect data in the queue.

Producer command:

```
echo 'Hello, World' | kcat -P -b localhost:9092 -t foobar
```

[image: queued records]

[image: flowfile content]

Comment: Thank you so much for everything. Although your log only works when I receive messages from Kafka, it helped me to review all the requirements again, including the versions. After analyzing the Kafka Broker version and adapting the ConsumeKafka Processor to version 2.6, I was able to receive the messages from the topics in Kafka. Thanks again so much for helping me!